# Displaying a sharepoint document library inside a MS Teams tab; Document library tab Vs Sharepoint Vs Website

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, microsoft-teams, integration

I want to show a document library inside many MS Teams as a tab, i could do this using any of these options:-

1. Document Library
2. SharePoint
3. WebSite

[image]

but i am not sure when i should use these options, and which is more suitable/recommended to be used to show a document library inside many MS Teams tabs?

Answer (score 3):

You use "Document Library" for Document Libraries, "SharePoint" for SharePoint pages or generic lists, and "Website" for non-SharePoint webpages.

Additionally, you can add a document library as a special folder inside the Files tab by clicking the "Add cloud storage" button.

So, the most suitable tab to add would be the first one, unless you want it to display alongside the channels own files.

Comment: Ok thanks for the helpful reply. so i think i will go with the "Document Library" option. i did not know that i can add a SharePoint document library as a folder inside MS Teams, but will this add the users inside the MS Teams to have access to the document library? or adding a document library as a Cloud storage inside MS Teams will not have any effect on the permissions?

Comment: It will not do any changes to the permissions on the Team or library, the permissions of the library will be respectef. If the answer was satisfactory, please remember to give it a vote and mark it as accepted as this will help others!

Comment: thanks for the reply, will see if i will get other replies, and of course will mark your question as answer ..